# phpmyadmin .ini file, maximize execution php script time

Tags: php, configuration, ini

Is it possible to make changes to .ini php file to maximize the excecution time of php scripts?

I am owner of a reseller package at hostgator and a vps at inmotionhosting. There isn't any property or option to change it via cpanel or whm.

So I ask if there is any other way, like to manually create this file, place it to the server via ftp and restart php my admin.

Comment: you need to ask your hosting provider about your server setup and what they allow and do not allow

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the php folder where php.ini is held then you can just edit that.

The property you are looking for is called `max_execution_time`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can edit the php.ini usually located in `/usr/local/lib/php.ini` then restart httpd which will update it. You can't normally access php.ini via **FTP** so you would need to use **SSH** to do this or find php.ini via a file manager on your container software.

Alternatively, you can set execution limits on a per script basis with

[set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Additionally you can use

[ini_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

to change the value of any php configuration variable at runtime. Try `ini_set('max_execution_time')`. Your host may have disabled certain configurations so this will not work on all servers.